# How to remove the HTML <P> </P> Tag from CSS

Tags: html, css, tags, paragraph

Working in `Webobjects`, The result of my page is like :

```
<p> Hello World </p>
```

I want to remove the `<p></p>` Tag from the result with the help of CSS.
This  `<p> Hello World </p>` coming under the `<div class="test">`.

Is there any way to apply CSS to the class test to remove the `<p> </p>` tag.

Comment: You can hide it use `p{display:none}`

Comment: @Akshay: In that case Hello World also not displayed.

Comment: As i know you can't remove p tag using css. Yes you can remove padding and margin which comes due to p tag. using: `p { margin:0; padding:0 }`

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

With css you only can change its behaviour. But you can hide it:

```
div.text p {display: none}
```

**Edit:** If you only want to avoid it's bejaviour you can change it. For example:

```
div.text p {
    display: block !improtant;
    margin: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

But, anyway, p tag always remains there even you don't visually notice it (good if this is your goal). If you want to don't find it, for example, when exploring document from javascript, you **should** remove it from javascript.

For example, using jQuery:

```
$("div.text p").each(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    var contents = me.html();
    var parent = me.parent();
    me.remove();
    parent.append(contents); 
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned  I want to remove the <p> </p> tag not the content inside the <p> </p> tag, so display:none also not displayed the contents.

Comment: Sorry. But, as I said, css can't change document structure, only can modify it's behaviour. If you only want to avoid its effects you should remove unwanted behaviours. For example, you can do "div.text p {display:block; border:0px !important; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important}"

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using css you will need jquery or javascript

```js
$('p').contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Hello World </p>
```

but you can use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to replace `<p>` with `<div>`

```js
$( "p" ).replaceWith( "<div class=test> Hello World </h2>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Hello World </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, This approach I tried, I want to achieve this with some CSS Tricks/behaviour, Is it not possible at all ?